# Concatenating function result with string in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function log-file {
  param($message)
  Add-Content -path $logfile -Value "$(Get-Date) $message"
}

function ping-server {
  param($server)
  $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
  $ping.Send("$server")
}

log-file "Pinging server = " + (ping-server $server).status
```

How can I get the above to work with one line rather than doing this:

```
$pingable = (ping-server $server).status
log-file "Pinging server = $pingable"
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-to-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell

Answer (score 6):

Try making this modification to the log-file function call

```
log-file $("Pinging server = " + (ping-server $server).status)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to concatenate/glue strings in PowerShell, but I prefer **avoiding the plus sign**, because its main role is addition and sometimes messes things up with strings.

I think more efficient and readable way is the following:

```
log-file $("Pinging server = $((ping-server $server).status)")
```

Just wrap your function in $() and place it inside the double quotes.

[Read more](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/keep-your-hands-clean-use-powershell-to-glue-strings-together/);